# TypeScript generic type infer

Tags: typescript

I have an object with some fields, and I'm going to implement an update function, which can modify value of existed key in my object. How can I restrict the function to only accept the existed keys in object, and the new value's type must be the same as the original value.

```js
const defaultData = {
    name: '',
    count: 0,
    desc: '',
    visited: false,
};

type DataType = typeof defaultData;
type Keys = keyof DataType;

let data = Object.assign({}, defaultData);

// after tried, I found out this works. But not quite understand it
function updateData<T extends Keys, P extends DataType[T]>(k: T, value: P){
    data[k] = value;
}

updateData('name', 'hehe');
updateData('count', false);
```

I'm wondering whether this is the **ONLY** way to define the `updateData` function. What is `P extends DataType[T]` is? I tried to use `<T extends Keys, P = DataType[T]>`, but it is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your option is an ok one, a simpler one would be to not use the `P` type argument at all as we don't care about the actual type passed in, we only care that is is compatible with `DataType[T]`:

```
function updateData<T extends Keys>(k: T, value: DataType[T]){
    data[k] = value;
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgUwGYEMCuAbKARFUUwC8MA3gFAyUxgoC2CAXDAOTMA0FVoaYUTADByrwEEYE1ZCqANwCWEWVARwmqDBAQcAvgG4yZKAE8ADghi58AFRNniR0yCQjUmHHhR77ZgNIJDEIhgAaz9Hc3drUz0yDARYOHdAgHkAIwArBGAoADoUCAUAczAAChItNmd0LAsUAEpopB4s2XAYNGMEpRqAHksYBAAPJTA4AN9-AD5ioKZLCukUDDRGcKsbAG1LAF1a8mFOlHWgrcCFpYQ9LX12zoQa4uYaenYWAAsEd+Z6shu8O-cHtxeC81Bp6kA)

The reason `P extends DataType[T]` works while `P = DataType[T]` does not is that they do very different things. `P extends DataType[T]` means that `P` need to be a subtype of `DataType[T]`. `P = DataType[T]` means that if `P` can't be inferred, `DataType[T]` should be used (but `P` can be any type not necessarily a sub type of `DataType[T]`)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do that in a more generic way, so that you don't have to write `type DataType = typeof defaultData;` etc for every data type you want to update.

```
function updater<T extends {}>(data: T) {
  return function <K extends keyof T>(key: K, value: T[K]) {
    data[key] = value
  }
}
```

This is a generic higher order function that creates an updater function for a specific data type. It can be used like this:

```
let myData = {
  name: '',
  count: 0,
};


let updateMyData = updater(myData);

updateMyData('name', 'hehe'); // ok
updateMyData('blag', 'hehe'); // fail
updateMyData('count', false); // fail
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAjABwCYEMYFMBOAPACrK4AeeEGAzsgN4C+AfABTYxYBcyxAlA2DJk+XDDD4U4aPCTJCAaTKVc1OgGtcATwQhebTVp4KANMgBuWADZhcPYgG0FAXQH0hw5BywPDz5AC8Fta2HozA4cDAVmLIALZaACI4WIGCwhBYcXbIAOS5Jh5QCJAwPAAMhYwA3FHRsegcuACySSlpjTgErAnJnHy1wJ14rX1YrLmZ2QV5ABa487kDyAD0K8gI6kOYXaMpEwBGVlgA5jO584vLa8ggWHBW2017nBPFpTN3VjS41+t3DyiMRg8TanAATGl3MIMLgaFAePlCsJzHAaHA8BgeF8flVBsDUDsRmCsJCgsNur0UuC+FEKS9SRNYfDzpdcEtqqt1psnrsSeDDsczmYLgt2X9bvdHvT+RNUejMTMAMwSgGPIA)